# How to count the number of files whose name contains a vowel

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I was trying to code a script that counts the number of files with a vowel in a directory.

If I use

```
find $1 -type f | wc -l
```

I get the number of files in the directory $1, but I do not know how to use grep to count just the one with a vowel, I was trying something like this

```
find $1 -type f | grep -l '[a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U]' | wc -l
```

Comment: Your question is about a single directory but your `find` command will traverse all its subdirectories.  Maybe add `-maxdepth 1` if that is not your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this gnu `find` command to count all the files with at least one vowel:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*[aeiou]*' -printf ".\n" | wc -l
```

`-iname '*[aeiou]*'` glob pattern will match only filename with at least one of the `a,e,i,o,u` (ignore case).

Remove `-maxdepth 1` if you want to count files recursively in sub directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept counting directories:

```
ls -d *a* *e* *i* *o* *u* *y* *A* *E* *I* *O* *U* *Y* | wc -l
```

Otherwise:

```
find $1 -type f | grep -i '[aeiouy]' | wc -l
```

Comment: Also known as `ls -d *[aeiouAEIOU]*` (I omitted the *y* which was not in the spec).

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt fails for two reasons.  First, `-l` does not make sense if grep is reading in a pipeline, since the purpose of `-l` is to print only the input file that matched, but in this case the only input file is stdin.  Second, your syntax is wrong.  Try:

```
... | grep -i '[aeiou]' | ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use commas in a character group expression (the thing in `[]` brackets)

The best way is to first do a `find(1)` to get the files you want to scan.  Then you need the base names, as the path info is not valid.  Finally, you need to grep with `[aeiouAEIOU]` to get only the lines with a vowel in, and finally use `wc(1)` to count lines.

```
find ${DIRECTORY} -type f -print | sed -e 's@^.*/@@' | grep '[aeiouAEIOU]' | wc -l
```

`-type f` allows you to select just files (not directories).  The `sed(1)` command edits the output, line by line, eliminating the first part of the name up to the last `/` character.  The grep filters names with at least one vowel and discards the others, and finally `wc -l` counts the lines.

Comment: `sed | grep` is an [antipattern](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep). `grep | wc -l` is also an antipattern.

Comment: I've been reading the link and have my own comments to that page.  Don't follow blindly the recommendations there, as not all `grep`s support the `-c` option, as not all `grep`s support editing.  The anciend filosophy of unix was *make programs that do little things, but do them well.*  If you follow that page, why not use `perl(1)` then?  Thank you for the downvote either.